# Error message displayed when opening Eclipse: "An error has occurred. See the log file null"

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Windows 10 and jre1.8.0_51. I don't know why when I start Eclipse it always displays an alert message "An error has occurred. See the log file null."

And I cannot open Eclipse thereafter. I tried to search Google and have no best solution. I uninstalled JRE and installed it again, but it still produces the same problem.

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using?

Comment: YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.log open file and please put the error trace.

Comment: Try to run as admin

Comment: For more recent searchers, the above error can occur when trying to run older Eclipse installs with newer Java version (eg. 11, 16).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had same issue.
To resolve it : Go to Eclipse directory -> Open CMD -> eclipse -clean

worked well.

Answer (score 24):

Try to launch it from the console like:

```
C:\path\to\eclipse\eclipse -clean
```

Also you try to can delete the file to fix the problem permanently as suggested [here](http://www.metod.si/job-found-still-running-after-platform-shutdown-eclipse/). Command would be something like below for windows.

```
del  YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
```

Comment: The "eclipse -clean" command did the magic for me :) (Win 8.1 here btw)

Comment: Update though: It seemed to be too late, my entire workspace went trash...^^ Built it up from fresh now. Sometimes I just should not update everything :/

Comment: This also worked for with with Eclipse Neon on linux.

Comment: -clean fixed it for me.  Thanks!

Comment: del  YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap worked for me

Answer (score 11):

I ran into the same problem. When I try running eclipse as Administrator, the problem went away.

Comment: Yeah, so of the `java.io` stuff that it was referencing on launch required admin privileges for me

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with Windows 10. Give full control to your user in security settings on the eclipse and workspace folders.

I also found the read only property was set on the eclipse and workspace folders, which I unset.

The log file can be found in the `eclipse\configuration` folder.

Answer (score 4):

I deleted `.metadata` from the workspace and ran the eclipse as *run as administrator* and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found that running Eclipse (STS 3.9) as administrator worked, which is a permissions issue. Giving the required users read/write/execute permissions to the config and workspace folders did the trick (they couldn't write previously).

Answer (score 1):

I too came across the same error. 
My log file says :
 **Java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Eclipse\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi.manager.fileTableLock (Access is denied)**

So, i copied entire eclipse in another folder and it worked for me.

So, for me the problem was write access, because eclipse need write across configuration folder, in my case eclipse was unzipped by some other user and i didn't have the access.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, and then I found out that, the eclipse distribution works fine with JDK 8. I previously ran JDK 10 and I got this error. Uninstalling JDK 10 and installing JDK 8 fixed the issue for me.
Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure your java version is compatible with your eclipse version!**

It is an easy solution that worked for me. Deleting the .metadata did not worked. I was using eclipse MARS 2.0 but set my JAVA_HOME to java 17. However, Mars does not support java 17. As soon as I switched it back to java 14 eclipse launched again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your eclipse launch folder does not have read only property/attribute

My eclipse resides at below location and If I right click ->properties- checked attributes were read only. I unchecked read only and restarted eclipse. Issue was resolved.
C:\Users\Ashish\Downloads\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64 (1)\eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm just share, if you can not copy file .metadata on mac because that file invisible (JUST on Mac issue), try this step:

1. compress your file .metadata backup
2. copy file .zip
3. paste file .zip to path/workspace
4. double click file .zip
5. done :-)

Answer (score 0):

Open the eclipse.exe with the right mouse button and open with admin rights and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the  same problem and deleting the file .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap and try it should work

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Java JDK
2. Reinstall JDK 8
3. Run Eclipse as administrator

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.snap` file from `<WORKSPACE-DIRECTORY>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources`

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned solutions didn't work for me under Windows OS. 
I just deleted **.manager** from **eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.core.runtime** and from **eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi** and the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the **.metadata** folder in eclipse. That should resolve the issue. The **.metadata** folder is recreated by eclipse once it is able to launch successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error in **My Windows 10 pc** while using **Eclipse 2020 version**

Just **delete** the .metadata folder and then try to run eclipse again it will solve the problem and  run fine. .Metadata folder will get  created once again by itself as we open eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

**I uninstalled JRE and installed it again, but it still produces the same problem.**

Turns out that my version of eclipse doesn't work with jdk17 (installed it using Amazon Corretto 17). So uninstalled Amazon Corretto 17 (automatically uninstalls jdk17 as well) and installed jdk11 using Amazon Corretto 11.

Thankfully worked for me! What I tried was similar to what you tried, but worth trying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install Eclipse or add **vm** path in your **eclipse.ini** file.

```
-vm
C:/<Your Path>/jdk1.8.0/jre/bin/javaw.exe
```

*Note: Change javaw.exe path according to your system*