# Cant open eclipse after installing vue.js codemix

Tags: eclipse

After I restart my eclipse I got this error

> An error has occurred. See the log file \.metadata\.log

I tried to delete the *.metadata folder* and run the eclipse as administrator Ive still got the error

This is what Ive tried so far but none of this work for me

[display-error-message-when-open-the-eclipse-an-error-has-occurred-see-the-log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944658/display-error-message-when-open-the-eclipse-an-error-has-occurred-see-the-log)

[an-error-has-occured-please-see-log-file-eclipse-juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333825/an-error-has-occured-please-see-log-file-eclipse-juno#)

This is the inside of log

```
!SESSION 2018-05-31 12:13:30.531 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.3.M20170301-0400
java.version=1.8.0_101
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.php.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 2 0 2018-05-31 12:13:34.098
!MESSAGE InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(): registration for component com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.quickopeneventbu is already disposed! 

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-05-31 12:13:34.154
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core (9).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.CodeCore.start() of bundle com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:795)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2391)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2156)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.engine.JsonUtil.<clinit>(JsonUtil.java:48)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.languages.ValidationService.populateHiddenLaunchConfigurations(ValidationService.java:95)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.languages.ValidationService.init(ValidationService.java:51)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.languages.ValidationService.<init>(ValidationService.java:47)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.languages.ValidationService.getInstance(ValidationService.java:57)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.CodeCore.start(CodeCore.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
    ... 51 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.engine.JsonUtil.<clinit>(JsonUtil.java:48)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.languages.ValidationService.populateHiddenLaunchConfigurations(ValidationService.java:95)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.languages.ValidationService.init(ValidationService.java:51)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.languages.ValidationService.<init>(ValidationService.java:47)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.languages.ValidationService.getInstance(ValidationService.java:57)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core.CodeCore.start(CodeCore.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.startup(Workspace.java:2391)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.open(Workspace.java:2156)
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start(ResourcesPlugin.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
```

Comment: This is a version constraint problem you should report to its authors.

Comment: @nitind in eclipse or codemix?

Comment: vue.js codemix.

Comment: @nitind so to fix this I need to upgrade my eclipse?

Comment: Obviously, Genuitec CodeMix broke your Eclipse IDE. Genuitec says, [_"For the versions our plugin lists as supporting, we test, period."_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436029/keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse-oxygen/45447927?noredirect=1#comment80730988_45447927). About the technology used by Genuitec (weaving instead of using API as all other plug-ins do), I had a [discussion with Tim Webb from Genuitec on Twitter](https://twitter.com/howlger/status/923150050016022528).

Comment: @howlger I see so far im installing neon and oxygen eclipse still got the error.

Comment: Sure, because the issue is not caused by Eclipse. The bundle/plug-in `com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core` fails to start and has also a problem with an OSGi declarative service (`org.eclipse.equinox.ds`: Eclipse Exquinox = OSGi implementation, ds = declarative service). Choose carefully which plugins you install.

Comment: @howlger thank you for the reminder sir. So for now i just open `.vue` files as javascript editor.

Comment: Missed this post earlier.  @howlger thanks for staying on top of us ;)  This issue didn't have anything to do with weaving, etc. though appreciate the sharing of FUD.  We had an earlier release where our requirement to gson was not tightly bound so if you had an older version of gson in your Eclipse, the version from our site wasn't installed.

Comment: @Tim No one has claimed that this issue was caused by weaving. You claimed that [_"For the versions our plugin lists as supporting, we test, period"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436029/keyboard-shortcuts-in-eclipse-oxygen/45447927?noredirect=1#comment80730988_45447927) but this issue shows otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for bringing this up.  In an older version of CodeMix, our requirement to the GSON plugin wasn't fully bound.  This was fixed not too long after this question was asked.  There have been many changes in CodeMix since the first technical preview builds with some exciting new functionality.  If you haven't had a chance to do so, I suggest you updating and try again!

We're about to end our technical preview phase.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

delete [\your directory]\eclipse\plugins\com.genuitec.*.jar, then eclipse is live again

Answer (score 1):

CodeMix install broke so badly I couldn't even quit Eclipse.

rm -fr $HOME/.codemix*

Removing $HOME/.codemix* did enough that when Eclipse process was killed (kill -9) I could start Eclipse, then remove CodeMix the normal way.