# i find this error when i run my jsp dynamic web project in tomcat server using eqlipse

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and tried to run the progect on my Apache Tomcat v9.0 Server in which I made html and jps files executable using eqlipse ide, it still gave me this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type: Status Report

Message: The requested resource [/ddddd/] is not available

Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.45
```

But if just run the html file it works as well as the jsp file. but if i run the whole project ddddd i find that i don't know why.??

Comment: Will this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43186803/15590269

Comment: then i unintsalled the eqlipse and again download it...now i'm in an another problem...when i open it i find An error has occured . See the log file null..

Comment: Ok, Now will this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36824598/15590269

Comment: I was already in the page...Go to Eclipse directory -> Open CMD -> eclipse -clean...how to do it??

Comment: On your eclipse's console Type "C:\path\to\eclipse\eclipse -clean" Will it help you?